# Can't find Windows Spotlight Images in usual location

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

My Windows Spotlight (lock-screen) Images are working fine.  About once every day or two I get a new image.  But when I look in the "usual" location to find the images on disk:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
```

**The files there are all over 4 months old!**  And when I add a .jpg extension to them the images are *not* windows spotlight images, but something else.

Any idea where I can find the windows spotlight images that I am seeing on my lock screen.

---

Responding to comment by @Ramhound ... there appears to be no "Creative" under "Lock Screen" at that point in the registry:

[image]

Furthermore, the only thing under the other folders (FeedManager, etc.) under "Lock Screen" is `(Default)  REG_SZ  (value not set)` for all of them.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the keys contained within **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\Creative** specifically **HotspotImageFolderPath**

Comment: @Ramhound  Thanks.  I've updated the question.